# In SDIO interface how interrupts are registered

Tags: linux, wifi, driver, device, interrupt

I want to know about SDIO interface. I googled about it but didn't get any convencing link for the same. I want to know about interrupt registeration in SDIO interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look at drivers/mmc/core sdio_irq.c ?
Check sdio_claim_irq function which launches sdio_irq_thread thread.
When there is an interrupt this thread calls the registered interrupt handler.

Comment: how do i check if my driver is using SDIO interface ?

Comment: for interrupt registration if your driver calls sdio_claim_irq then it is using the interface. Also if functions like sdio_claim_host are called from your driver. You can see brcmf open source implementation for details.